# Change a string to an integer - pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, delphi, turbo-pascal

I don't know how "xa" can convert in to 10 in pascal. I just use:

```
Val('xa',value,return);
```

And value = 10, return = 0. I'm just a newbie, anybody can explain this? I know this won't like the ASCII cause that is just a character.

And I'm using Free Pascal :)

I tested in Free Pascal, when use `xa`, `0xa` and `$xa`. So, I think it understand the special character like "$","0" without calling it. Is that right?

Comment: Are you asking how does exactly function "val" works?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Delphi treats `0xa` and `xa` the same way as `$a`.

Comment: @LURD: Ok, I knew about `'0xa'`, because that should work in C and C++ too, but I am flabbergasted about `'xa'`.

Comment: I don't mean how does the function "val" works, just wondering how it can understand 'xa', it should work like that if that is "0xa"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since early Delphi's, the core integer conversion routines don't do just number sequences, but also some specials like Pascal "$924" for hex or C  style 0x02).

FreePascal adopted it when it later started adding Delphi compatibility (roughly 1997-2003). Beside this difference, another different is that the last parameter (RETURN in your example) changed from WORD (in Turbo Pascal) to integer/longint in Delphi.

IOW, the routine accepts the x and thinks you mean to convert a C style hex number, and then interprets the "a" according to Stuart's table.

It also interprets % as binary, and & as octal.

Try

```
val('$10',value,return);
writeln(value,' ' ,return);  // 16 0
val('&10',value,return);
writeln(value,' ' ,return);  // 8 0
val('%10',value,return);
writeln(value,' ' ,return);  // 2 0
```

and compare the results.

Note that this probably won't work for very old Pascal's like Turbo Pascal, and Free Pascals from before the year 2000. The % and & are FPC specific to match the literal notation extensions (analogous to $, but for binary and octal)

```
var x : Integer
begin
x:=%101010;  //42
x:=&101;     //65
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Love you so much

Comment: Btw, I created an entry in our bugtracker for the documenter to expand the VAL() entry with this info.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work with all Pascal compilers, and you didn't say what Pascal compiler you are using, but it looks like, the x in 'xa' says that this is a hexadecimal (base 16) number, and the value of the digits in a hexadecimal number are as follows:

> ```
> Digit Value
> 0      0
> 1      1
> 2      2
> 3      3
> 4      4
> 5      5
> 6      6
> 7      7
> 8      8
> 9      9
> a     10
> A     10
> b     11
> B     11
> c     12
> C     12
> d     13
> D     13
> e     14
> E     14
> f     15
> F     15
> ```

Comment: I confirm, the same happened to me on windows using StrToInt(): it understood hex numbers out of the box. I am not sure, it was lazarus (so, freepascal) or, perhaps, even Delphi 6?

Comment: The $ and 0x/x stuff is Delphi, at least D4, but wouldn't be surprised D2 too. I never used (16-bit) D1. Probably it supports 0x because of BCB, since the IDE is written in Delphi afaik.